# Ajax response not displaying on datatable while viewing on Firefox and Edge browsers

Tags: c#, json, ajax, datatable

I have i report that displays fine on Google chrome, but while trying to view on Firefox or Edge browser, the json response displays on the browser instead of the datatable. Sample response below:
" 
 [{\"RegisteredBy\":\"Admin\",\"PatientRegNo\":\"De723\",\"PaymentType\":\"Cash\"}]"

I have tried including the below code:

```
contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',

return Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is my Ajax function:

```
$("#searchBtn").click(function () {     
        var url = $("#frmReport").attr('action');
        var str = $("#frmReport").serialize();
        $("#searchBtn").prop("disabled", true);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: str,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",              
            success: function (_data) {
                var arr = $.map(JSON.parse(_data), function (el) { return el });                   
                table.clear();
                table.destroy();
                $('#tblReport').dataTable({
                    data: arr,
                    columns: [
                        { "data": "RegisteredBy"},
                        { "data": "PatientRegNo"},
                        { "data": "PaymentType"},                           
                    ],
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel',
                        {
                            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                            orientation: 'portrait',
                            pageSize: 'A4'
                        }

                    ]
                });

            }
        });
        table = $("#tblReport").DataTable();
    });
});
```

My JsonResult Code:

```
getEntries = superAdminForBillingRepository.GetByRegNoOnly(regNo);
var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getEntries);
return Json(data);
```

I want to be able to view the ajax response on the datatable on any browser

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with sample json data to show the different behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

try to invoke your table like this:

```
var tableTypeOfClientInfo = $('#tableTypeOfClientInfo ').DataTable({
                       "destroy": true,
                       "responsive":{
                         "details": {
                         renderer: function ( api, rowIdx, columns ) {
                           var data = $.map( columns, function ( col, i ) {
                             return col.hidden ?
                               '<tr data-dt-row="'+col.rowIndex+'" data-dt-column="'+col.columnIndex+'">'+
                                 '<td>'+col.title+':'+'</td> '+
                                 '<td>'+col.data+'</td>'+
                               '</tr>' :
                               '';
                           } ).join('');

                           return data ?$('<table/>').append( data ) :false;
                         }
                       }
                     },
                       "autoWidth": false,
                             "ajax": {
                                 "url": 'some.php',
                                 "method": 'POST',
                                 data:{action:"SLC", categoryId:id}
                             },
                             "columns": [
                                 {"data": "identification_number"},
                                 {"data": "address"},
                                 {"data": "birthday"},
                                 {"data": "phone"},
                                 {"data": "mail"}
                             ],
                             "language":{"url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"},
                               "columnDefs": [
                                 {
                                   "className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"
                                  }
                               ]
                         });
```